# Not all variables bound ORA-01008: not all variables bound error

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, plsql, oracle-sql-developer

I am using Oracle SQL developer. I am running a query on employees table which is by default, having columns like
first_name, last_name, employee_id, email, phone_no, hire_date, job_id, salary, commission_pct, manager_id, department_id.

I am writting a report that displays the last name and salary of employees who earn more than an amount that the user specifies after a prompt. 
If you enter 12000, it should display all employees earning more than 12000.
Eg: Salary_value: 12000.

My report is like this

```
select last_name, salary
from employees
where employees.salary>&sal;
```

But I am getting an error like this

```
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
01008. 00000 - "not all variables bound"
*Cause:
*Action:
Vendor code 1008
```

Clearly there is nothing in the cause section. I need help please. Thanks in advance.

BUT I can succesfully run it from Sql plus command line utility as well as I can run it as a *.sql file. But It is not working in case of a report. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have set `define` to `off`.

```
set define off
select last_name, salary from employees where employees.salary>&sal;

Error starting at line : 2 in command -
select last_name, salary from employees where employees.salary>&sal
Error at Command Line : 2 Column : 31
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01008: not all variables bound
01008. 00000 -  "not all variables bound"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Set it to `on` (which is the default value by the way):

```
set define on
select last_name, salary from employees where employees.salary>&sal;
```

With `define` set to `on`, SQL Developer will prompt for a value for the variable `&sal`.

Comment: After set define on I am getting an error "missing or invalid option".

Comment: Suspiciously I can successfully run it in Sql Plus command line utility. It is running as usual. But in case of report in sql developer this error is generating.

Comment: @AgnivaDutta substitution variables works in sql worksheet but for reports you need to use bind variables so your where clause for report should be `where employees.salary>:sal;`